# Over 48 hours since I qualified for the tenacious badge

Tags: support, badges

I think I qualified for the [tenacious badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/tenacious) on the weekend.

But almost 48 hours later I have not received the badge.

Should I be concerned yet. Most people seem to think 24 hours is reasonable. I have 6 accepted 0 score answers, out of 18 total answers, so I'd be interested to hear if I've missed something on the criteria.

Comment: I know it's silly to worry about these things....

Comment: Your tenacity in following up on this important issue shows that you deserve the badge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258):

**Tenacious**

- silver; awarded once; same family as Unsung Hero (gold)
- Have more than five accepted answers with a score of zero, and have those zero-score accepted answers account for at least 20% of all your accepted answers

  - Only accepted answers at least ten days old are considered
  - Community Wiki answers, deleted answers, and self-accepted answers are not included in any calculations
- Was originally named Tireless.
- Sources: How long do Tireless and Unsung Hero badges take to be awarded?, a SO team member who checked the source code in chat

Comment: Well that answers it then. The most recent accepted answer is less than 10 days old.

Comment: Yes, that does. Thanks Julian.